# Identify only the duplicate records from a file and print only the duplicate records into a new file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have many 10 columns in a CSV file, out of which column 1, 3 and 4 have duplicate records in it. Need to identify these duplicate records and store them into a separate TXT file.
File is a ',' delimited

for example:

```
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,16573.34,0,C,6/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,16573.34,0,C,6/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,6591.5,0,O,23/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,305592.33,0,C,27/07/2017
13256433,I,101095000000,I,31/03/2019,TD21,102992.06,0,C,20/03/2017
13256492,I,101095000000,I,31/03/2019,TD21,102992.06,0,C,20/03/2017
11595044,I,101225000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,70000,0,O,14/10/2016
13222989,I,101296000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,53850,0,O,21/09/2018
13222989,I,101296000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,534850,0,O,21/09/2019
```

Output file

```
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,16573.34,0,C,6/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,6591.5,0,O,23/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,305592.33,0,C,27/07/2017
13222989,I,101296000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,53850,0,O,21/09/2018
13222989,I,101296000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,534850,0,O,21/09/2019
```

AWK Command which I have wrote but didn't work is:

```
awk -F, 'dups{a[$1,$3,$4]++; next} a[$1,$3,$4]>1' source.CSV > Dups.txt
```

Please advise

Comment: Should there be 4 lines starting with `14479305,I,101013000000,I` instead of 3 in the expected output or should there only be 1 line starting with `13222989,I,101296000000,I` instead of 2? It depends if you want all records with duplicate keys or only subsequent records with duplicate keys output.

Comment: It appears that you want to extract the records with non-unique 1,3,4 fields, and then get the unique records from that set. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there! only you needed to process the input file twice (plus some fixes), first time finding the duplicates count based on your criteria (column#1, #3, #4) and at the second time filter out those lines having count>1 into output file, so:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ dups[$1,$3,$4]++; next} dups[$1,$3,$4]>1' source.CSV source.CSV > Dups.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is grouped by the key values you can do this in 1 pass of the input and storing just 1 line at a time in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }
{ key = $1 FS $3 FS $4 }
key == prevKey {
    print prevRec $0
    prevRec = ""
    next
}
{
    prevRec = $0 ORS
    prevKey = key
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,16573.34,0,C,6/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,16573.34,0,C,6/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,6591.5,0,O,23/03/2015
14479305,I,101013000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,305592.33,0,C,27/07/2017
13222989,I,101296000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,53850,0,O,21/09/2018
13222989,I,101296000000,I,31/03/2019,TD01,534850,0,O,21/09/2019
```

If it wasn't grouped that way, just do `sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,4 file | awk -f tst.awk` instead.

I'm assuming above that you want ALL lines with duplicate keys printed, not just the lines after the first occurrence of each key.